# Is a Pokemon's CP or IVs more important when choosing which Pokemon to defend a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

That is, if I can catch a Pokemon with a CP of 1850, but then I checked the IV and perfection, and its perfection can be any where from 55% to 76%.

Now, if I have another Pokemon with a perfection level of 97.8%, and I spent time powering it up, but so far its CP is only 1850, the same as the other Pokemon.

Now, these two Pokemons have the same CP but different IV and perfection. If I let them stay at a gym, do they have the same amount of chance of winning in general due to the same CP, or is it hard to say?

In some situation, if I catch a Pokemon with CP of 1950 but perfection of only 60%, then I wonder if I should let it stay at the gym or let my Pokemon with CP 1850 and perfection 97.8% stay at the gym.

Comment: It's not so simple. IVs grant a little bonus to the Pokemon's stats, CP itself is an indicator of the overall stats. When defending a gym you should consider the HP and the moveset, not only CP.

Answer (score 2):

**IVs are included in the CP amalgamate.** In general, two Pokemon with the same moveset and species will be roughly equivalent if they also have the same CP; if one of them has greater IVs, then the other will undoubtedly have a higher level.

There is *some* variance because the CP formula values Attack quadratically more than Defense or Stamina, even though their respective effect in battle is proportional (with Stamina contributing slightly more due to the fact that it also serves as a [reservoir of Energy](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4wqk0j/i_did_some_testing_and_can_confirm_defending/)). Thus, Pokemon with higher Attack will be over-rated, and those with lower attack will be under-rated. IVs will, naturally, contribute to these proportions.

Answer (score 1):

As [explained by RustyMembers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/282627/25359) the IV is by far more important than the CP of a Pokemon. But actually equally or sometimes even more important is the Moveset of a Pokemon. A Pokemon with the best moveset dps wise but with lower IV will perform better than a similar one with a different moveset but higher IV %.

However there is some discussion about this but general consensus is that Moveset is more important than IV if the difference in % is not too high.

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4y3g28/is_moveset_really_more_important_than_ivs/) is a nice discussion on Reddit about the topic.

Answer (score -1):

> Each type of Pokemon has a base set of attributes for Stamina, Attack and Defence. Each specific Pokemon is "born" with it's own IV (individual values), that further increase these stats by 0-15 extra points. You can not change the IV's, not all Pokemon are born equal.
>   These IV's make small differences in the final power of a Pokemon. For example, the base attributes of a Charizard are 212, 182, 156. This would be the "worst" charizard available where all IV's are zero. With max IV's, a Charizard would have 227, 197, 171. Each of these Atk, Def and Stam values for Charizard are only 7-10% better. - [pokeassistant's IV calculator.](https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator)

If you leave the two pokemon with the same CP and different IV in a gym, the higher IV will have a slightly higher chance of surviving gym battles. As the IV is just an easy way of getting an overview of which pokemon has higher stats. The difference though will be VERY slightly. Also when deciding between 2 pokemon, the moveset should also be considered, as it can have a rather decent impact of the pokemon's power.

Instead of writing a long answer I will provide a link to a wiki page explaining IV in depth; [Pokemon GO IV explained](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Individual_Values_(IV)_and_Hidden_Stats)
Hope this helped you, if you have any further questions leave a comment and i will answer to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

The pokemon with a higher IV will have a better chance of surviving gym battles if you leave two pokemon with the same CP in a gym. read this [Pokemon Go pvp IV calculator](https://toolzweb.net/pokemon-go-pvp-iv-calculator/)  for more details

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/316032)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).